# String's replaceAll() method and escape characters

Tags: java, regex, string

The line

```
System.out.println("\\");
```

prints a single back-slash (`\`). And

```
System.out.println("\\\\");
```

prints double back-slashes (`\\`). Understood!

But why in the following code:

```
class ReplaceTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = "hello.world";
        s = s.replaceAll("\\.", "\\\\");
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

is the output:

```
hello\world
```

instead of

```
hello\\world
```

After all, the `replaceAll()` method is replacing a dot (`\\.`) with (`\\\\`).

Can someone please explain this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When replacing characters using regular expressions, you're allowed to use backreferences, such as `\1` to replace a using a grouping within the match.

This, however, means that the backslash is a special character, so if you actually want to use a backslash it needs to be escaped.

Which means it needs to actually be escaped twice when using it in a Java string. (First for the string parser, then for the regex parser.)

Comment: so basically what you are saying is that the string parser will first parse "\\\\" into "\\" which the regex parser will further parse into "\". Is that it??

Comment: Yeah, I'm a little confused, because in the example in the question, why wouldn't the string parser parse `\\.` as `\.` which regex would then parse to `.`?

Comment: @ametren that's correct. In the first part of the replace, it's really \. since he's escaping the dot since that has a special meaning as well, so that become's just '.' which then gets replaced by the string in the second argument.

Comment: Nevermind, just realized that I completely misread the question in the first place.

Answer (score 20):

The javadoc of [replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) says:

> Note that backslashes ( \ ) and dollar signs ($) in the replacement
>   string may cause the results to be different than if it were being
>   treated as a literal replacement string; see Matcher.replaceAll. **Use
>   Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)** to suppress the special
>   meaning of these characters, if desired.

Comment: +1 for the mention to Matcher.quoteReplacement !  
EDIT : remove the code (I do notm anage to indent it with mini-markdown)

Comment: There is a really important difference between `Pattern.quote` and `Matcher.quoteReplacement`. If you want to ignore metacharacters in search strings, you need to use the former (`Pattern.quote`). To ignore them in replacement strings (which have a slightly different syntax), you need to use the latter (`Matcher.quoteReplacement`). They are not compatible with each other, so *use the right one!*

Answer (score 8):

If you don't need regex for replacing and just need to replace exact strings, escape regex control characters before replace

```
String trickyString = "$Ha!I'm tricky|.|";
String safeToUseInReplaceAllString = Pattern.quote(trickyString);
```

Answer (score 7):

This is a formatted addendum to my comment

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\.", Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\"));
```

IS MORE READABLE AND MEANINGFUL THAN

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\.", "\\\\\\");
```

Answer (score 0):

The backslash is an escape character in Java Strings. e.g. backslash has a predefined meaning in Java. You have to use "\ \" to define a single backslash. If you want to define " \ w" then you must be using "\ \ w" in your regex. If you want to use backslash you as a literal you have to type \ \ \ \ as \ is also a escape character in regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in this particular case it would be easier to use replace instead of replace all.
Reverend Gonzo Has the correct answer when he talks about escaping the character.

Using replaceAll:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\.", "\\\\\\\\");
```

Using replace:

```
s = s.replaceAll(".", "\\");
```

replace just takes a string to match to, not a regular expression.

Comment: You mentioned replace() but you used replaceAll() twice, should you edit your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't like this implementation of regex. We should be able to escape characters with a single '\' , not '\'. But anyway if you want to get THIS.Out_Of_That you can do:

```
String prefix = role.replaceFirst("(\\.).*", "");
```

So you get prefix = THIS;