# Escape characters displayed in TextView

Tags: java, android, textview, escaping

In an Android app I'm making, I construct a `TextView` programmatically and pass a `String` to `setText`. The String I'm passing is obtained from another source, and it contains escape characters. Here's an example String:

```
AxnZt_35\/435\/46\/34
```

The `\/` should in fact be just `/`. But the `TextView` displays the whole thing exactly as in the above example.

The code I'm using to construct the `TextView`:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(context);
textView.setText(text);
textView.setTextColor(color);
textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
textView.setTextSize(14);
```

So my question is, how can I *not* display the extra `\`? I just want the above example displayed as:

```
AxnZt_35/435/46/34
```

Thanks.

**EDIT**

The String I provided above is just an example. There might be other characters in the String. For example, the character `/` or `\` by itself is perfectly valid. The problem is that `/` is displayed as `\/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from @Numan1617 is close, but for escape characters and `replaceAll()`, you have to escape them twice.

See [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865724/strings-replaceall-method-and-escape-characters).

So, the correct code in this case would be:

```
    String str = "AxnZt_35\\/435\\/46\\/34";

    System.out.println(str); //prints AxnZt_35\/435\/46\/34

    String s2 = str.replaceAll("\\\\/", "/"); 

    System.out.println(s2); //prints AxnZt_35/435/46/34
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and sample! The way you replaced (\\\\/) seems to do the trick... +1

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to replace all occurances of the \ before setting the text by using Strings replaceAll method:

```
textView.setText(text.replaceAll("\\", ""));
```

Comment: But won't that replace normal \ characters as well?

Comment: Tried that. The compiler complains that there's an invalid escape character in the string literal.

Comment: Isn't that equivalent to the first answer you posted? (Just having "\"). And AFAIK, it will replace _all_ \ characters. And besides, the compiler rejects that too. Says it's an illegal or unsupported escape sequence :-/

Answer (score 0):

Run this as plain Java

```
public class Klass{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new String("\\/"));
        System.out.println(new String("\\/").replaceAll("/", ""));
        System.out.println(new String("\\/").replaceAll("\\/", ""));
        System.out.println(new String("\\/").replaceAll("\\\\/", ""));
    }

}
```

The regex for \ is "\\": in regex one pair of \ is equal to one \ in the new String()

Comment: Yes, but the issue I had was, if I do escape using "\\", then it would replace all \'s in the text. But your last option is correct