# How to replace escape character in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, character

How can I replace escape character in Android? I have tried this but with no success:

```
 String a =finalObject.getString("icon").replaceAll("\ ", "");
```

Before I  can replace it, Android Studio is already giving me error.

Comment: If you want to replace <space>, you don't have to escape it... It's not a escape character... If you want to replace backslash, then use `replaceAll("\\\\","")`

Comment: thanks, i will try it and see

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865724/strings-replaceall-method-and-escape-characters

Answer (score 0):

Which escape character do you want to replace?
If you want to replace the character -->  \
you should write like this --> "\\"
and,
" --> "\""
' --> "\'"

Comment: sorryi dont quite understand, my code is this                                          String a =finalObject.getString("icon").replaceAll("\ ", "");

Comment: Try this:  String a =finalObject.getString("icon").replaceAll("\\", ""); And what's the error?

Answer (score 0):

String a =finalObject.getString("icon").replace("\\", "");