# Removing a /.br/ from a String in Java

Tags: java, mysql

I have a Java app that reads data from an Oracle database and then moves it to a MySQL database for research purposes. The data comes from an application where end users can basically enter free text. It appears that when the text is entered they are hitting returns that is causing a /.br/ to appear in the text. MySQL doesn't like the /.br/. I have tried several ways to remove the /.br/ with no luck

```
clinDisp = clinDisp.replaceAll("<.br */>", "");

clinDisp = clinDisp.replace("/.br/", "");

clinDisp = clinDisp.replace("<.br>", "");
```

No matter what I try the .br is always there and the insert for this row breaks. Also, if it matters I don't care if the line feed is lost, just something that will allow the String to insert.

Comment: It works [here](http://ideone.com/IG5DZP)

Comment: The / are actually \. Sorry. I think it is the \.br that is causing the issue, you are correct /.br/ works like above

Comment: \ is a escape character. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865724/strings-replaceall-method-and-escape-characters)

Comment: I figured it out, thanks sam2090, you were a big help.